# Find the next month for given date in mysql

Tags: mysql

Find the COUNT(next month Between next month +2DAYS)  for the created date in table(including Year wise Dec ,Jan like)

How to do this using mysql query
Query need for both datatype date and datetime

Comment: `DATE_ADD()` with `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` should work, although I don't know how that behaves in edge cases like January 31st.

Comment: Reference: [11.7. Date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) in the mySQL manual

Comment: Ya sure @pekka,
DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

Answer (score 11):

If you only want the MONTH, then use `SELECT MONTH('2011-03-28' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`

Works the same for DATE and DATETIME (replace the actual date I quoted with your own SQL and column name). For more info you can refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: how to get the count between nextmonth,nextmonth +2days

Comment: Count of what? Days? Minutes? Seconds? Months? Apples? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(whatever)
FROM
yourTable
WHERE
yourDateColumn BETWEEN NOW()+INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND NOW()+INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL 2 DAYS
```