# How to Fetch Upcoming Birthdays from Database?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, ms-access

I am having a database, from which I want to fetch list of people whose birthdays are in coming 15 days. I'm using ASP.NET C# and MS-Access as Database.
I googled a lot but Couldn't find correct explanation.
I'm using

```
select name,category,dob 
from family_details 
where Month(dob) >= Month(NOW()) and Day(dob) > Day(Now()) 
order by dob desc
```

this query, which gives list of Birthdays in Current months from today's date.
The result I want is the list of upcoming Birthday(say) of 15 days...

Comment: [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459287/find-the-next-month-for-given-date-in-mysql) think it answers your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Select Upcoming Birthdays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83531/sql-select-upcoming-birthdays)

Comment: It is not working...

Comment: @Filburt Why SQL Server answer for an MS Access SQL question?

Comment: @Filburt it is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `Add` 15 days in `current date` and get `month` from it.

```
select name,category,dob 
from family_details 
where Month(dob) in(Month(NOW()),Month(DateAdd(d,15,NOW()))) 
order by dob desc
```

`Month` can change in `next 15 days` so you also need to get that `month` .Here you will get `two values` one for `current month` and one after adding `15 days` in current date so if `month` has changed you will get value of that `month` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a helper function to get it right also for leaplings - those born on February 29th. The trick is to use `AddYears` which doesn't fail for leap years.

It can be created as an extension method of `DateTime`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates the next annual day of this instance of System.DateTime relative to today.
/// <para>Calculates correctly Feb. 28th as an annual day in common years for event dates of Feb. 29th.</para>
/// <para>If next annual day should be later than 9999-12-31, the annual day of year 9999 is returned.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="eventDate">The date of the event.</param>
/// <returns>The date of the upcoming annual day.</returns>
public static DateTime NextAnnualDay(this DateTime eventDate)
{
    return NextAnnualDay(eventDate, DateTime.Today);
}

/// <summary>
/// Calculates the next annual day of this instance of System.DateTime relative to a future date.
/// <para>Calculates correctly Feb. 28th as an annual day in common years for event dates of Feb. 29th.</para>
/// <para>If futureDate is earlier than this instance, the value of this instance is returned.</para>
/// <para>If next annual day should be later than 9999-12-31, the annual day of year 9999 is returned.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="eventDate">The date of the event.</param>
/// <param name="futureDate">The date from which to find the next annual day of this instance.</param>
/// <returns>The date of the upcoming annual day.</returns>
public static DateTime NextAnnualDay(this DateTime eventDate, DateTime futureDate)
{
    DateTime nextDate = eventDate;
    if (DateTime.MaxValue.Year - eventDate.Year == 0)
    {
        // No later next annual day can be calculated.
    }
    else
    {
        int years = futureDate.Year - eventDate.Year;
        if (years < 0)
        {
            // Don't calculate a hypothetical next annual day.
        }
        else
        {
            nextDate = eventDate.AddYears(years);
            if (nextDate.Subtract(futureDate).Days <= 0)
            {
                if (DateTime.MaxValue.Year - nextDate.Year == 0)
                {
                    // No later next annual day can be calculated.
                }
                else
                {
                    nextDate = eventDate.AddYears(years + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nextDate;
}
```

Then go like this (pseudo SQL):

```
select name, category, dob 
from family_details 
where dob.NextAnnualDay() between today and today.AddDays(15) 
order by dob desc
```

Finish using Linq or transform to parameterized SQL.